# How can I view CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests in my browser's console?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors, http-headers

I'm looking for a way to view the CORS pre-flight OPTIONS request when I make a CORS request. I wanted to see the server's response headers to help me debug a CORS issue I'm experiencing, but I couldn't find a a way to do this in Chrome or Firefox, in the Network tab or console of either.

I also installed the [HTTP Header Live](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-header-live/) addon, and it didn't help.

I'm using `jQuery.get(url);` to trigger my CORS request, where `url` is a URL at a different domain.

Comment: It shows up in the network tab by default

Comment: @Quentin that's where I'm looking, but I've yet to see any such request

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fB9Pb3H.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using jQuery.get(url); to trigger my CORS request

This will trigger a *simple* request without a preflight OPTIONS request.

You haven't fulfilled [any of the conditions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) required to trigger a preflight.

Since a preflight isn't being made, none show up in the developer tools.