# .net 5 CORS action call is locked even with EnableCors attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have a controller where i enabled cors

```
[EnableCors(Startup.CORS_POLICY_EXTERNAL)]
public class MasterController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestaConnessione()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

but with a simple fetch:

```
fetch("url/MasterController/TestaConnessione")
```

caller get `header CORS “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” missing`

but if the caller use iframe all works fine:

```
<iframe name="ifrReport" id="ifrReport"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        let form, input;
        form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = "URL";
        form.target = "ifrReport";
        form.method = "POST";       
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    })();

</script>
```

that's the startup config:

```
public const string CORS_POLICY_EXTERNAL = "CORS_POLICY_EXTERNAL";
        public const string CORS_POLICY_LOCAL = "CORS_POLICY_LOCAL";
    services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_POLICY_EXTERNAL,
                                      builder =>
                                      {
                                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                                          .AllowAnyHeader();
    
                                      });
                    options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_POLICY_LOCAL,
                                      builder =>
                                      {
                                          builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost")
                                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                                          .AllowAnyHeader();
    
                                      });
                });
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
                app.UseCors();
    
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
                var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
                app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
                app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Use developer tools of your browser to analyze the preflight requests and responses. That should get you started.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410051/chrome-not-showing-options-requests-in-network-tab
even looking in flag pages, cors visibility in my chrome browser is no more present

Comment: Chrome isn't the only web browser in this world.

Comment: in my corporate pc it is :(

Comment: maybe this is the reason:

i'm testing with fetch("url") and reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856345/how-can-i-view-cors-pre-flight-options-requests-in-my-browsers-console
I'm using jQuery.get(url); to trigger my CORS request
This will trigger a simple request without a preflight OPTIONS request.
You haven't fulfilled any of the conditions required to trigger a preflight.
Since a preflight isn't being made, none show up in the developer tools.

Comment: Is this happening on your internal or external call?  Could it be related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing

Comment: it talks about php config, as posted i (presume) correctly setup .net cors settings

Comment: seems you missed the the policy name in app.UseCors(...here policy name);

Comment: before i set CORS_POLICY_LOCAL inside and was not working, since i have two policy which one i have to use. reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985620/asp-net-core-use-multiple-cors-policies many user creates a custom cors middleware but i hope to found simpler way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was

```
app.UseCors();
```

or

```
app.UseCors("CORS_POLICY_LOCAL");
```

both doesn't work, i was forced to set

```
app.UseCors("CORS_POLICY_EXTERNAL");
```

further reading for reference:

- [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)
- [ASP .NET Core use multiple CORS policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985620/asp-net-core-use-multiple-cors-policies)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered multiple times, you can't bypass CORS just from client (your) side only. That feature needs to be enabled on the target server too. To quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931094/2377343):

> The header of the response, even if it's 200OK do not allow other origins (domains, port) to access the resources.
> You can fix this problem if you are the owner of the domain

Also, when you gave the example of `js` script that appends form to document and submits it, that is not related to CORS, because in that case, no AJAX/XHR request is made, instead it is form submit action, which can be done with any domain, regardless their CORS policy (*though there exist other measures too, which might even block form-submission from other domains, but that is not scope of this question*)

As as solution, you might try to trigger the request from client-side to backend of the app, which will make a request to target domain, and then your backend app provides that result back to client-side. That way, you will no need to worry about CORS policies.

Comment: maybe i miss something but controller and strtup with cors policy is on the server side: that is the action that other client app have to call